# comparing int value in list throws index out of range Error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm struggling to grasp the problem here. I already tried everything but the issue persist.
Basically I have a list of random numbers and when I try to compare the vaalues inside loop it throws "IndexError: list index out of range"

I even tried with range(len(who) and len(who) . Same thing. When put 0 instead "currentskill" which is int variable it works. What I don't understand is why comparing both values throws this Error. It just doesn't make sence...

Am I not comparing a value but the index itself ???

EDIT: I even tried with print(i) / print(who[i] to see if everything is clean and where it stops, and I'm definitelly not going outside of index

```
who = [2, 0, 1]
currentskill = 1

for i in who:
        if who[i] == currentskill: # IndexError: list index out of range
            who.pop(i)
```

Comment: You are attempting to index `who` with the value of `i`. Try with `if i == currentskill` instead.

Comment: Please include `who` and `currentskill` in your code so we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is once you start popping out elements list size varies

For eg take a list of size 6
But you iterate over all indices up to len(l)-1 = 6-1 = 5 and the index 5 does not exist in the list after removing elements in a previous iteration.

solution for this problem,
l = [x for x in l if x]
Here x is a condition you want to implement on the element of the list which you are iterating.

Comment: thank you ! I literally realize it just now. I forgot to take the size after removing items to consideration !

Comment: Yah it happens but not to worry just learn from them mate

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Hemesh

> The problem is once you start popping out elements list size varies

Problem solved. I'm just popping the element outside the loop now and it works:

```
def deleteskill(who, currentskill):
   temp = 0
   for i in range(len(who)):
       if who[i] == currentskill:
           temp = i
   who.pop(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. To get the index as well as the value, use the built-in function enumerate:

```
idx_to_remove = []
for idx, i in enumerate(who)::
    if i == currentskill: 
        idx_to_remove.append[idx]

for idx in reversed(idx_to_remove):
        who.pop(idx)
```

Edited after suggestion from @sabik

Comment: Better not to modify the list while iterating over it...

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

- mixing up the values and indexes, as pointed out by another answer; and
- modifying the list while iterating over it

The solution depends on whether you want to remove just one item, or potentially multiple.

For removing just one item:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(who)::
    if i == currentskill: 
        who.pop(idx)
        break
```

For removing multiple items:

```
to_remove = []
for idx, i in enumerate(who)::
    if i == currentskill: 
        to_remove.append[idx]
for idx in reversed(to_remove):
        who.pop(idx)
```

Depending on the situation, it may be easier to create a new list instead:

```
who = [i for i in who if i != currentskill]
```